# Как отправить html файл в качестве электронного письма?

Tags: php, html, email

Вот какая задача, есть форма и обработчик. Нужно через форму прикрепить html файл со сверстанным письмом для рассылки. Отправляю письмо в форме.

Встречаю файл в обработчике

```
$body = $_FILES['body']; // Получаю файл
$body_get_tmp_file = file_get_contents($body['tmp_name']); // Получаю содержимое файла
```

Делаю echo $body_get_tmp_file и останавливаю скрип exit; Выводится сверстанный html файл. Отлично!

Через функцию mail() отправляю $body_get_tmp_file на свою почту, но вместо ожидаемого сверстанного файла на почту прилетает html разметка.

Цель:

- В админке сайта в форме прикрепить html файл и отправить его на email'ы
- На почты должно прийти сверстанное письмо.

PS Хочу на своем сайте именно таким образом реализовать рассылку пользователям сайта)) Но готов выслушать все предложения и рекомендации)

UPD Решение найдено! Проблема была в заголовках! Исправил:

```
$headers.= "Content-Type: text/plain;charset=utf-8\r\n";
```

на

```
$headers.= "Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8\r\n";
```

Спасибо [Sergei Kirjanov](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/395779/sergei-kirjanov) за наводочку

Comment: A если отправить как аттачмент с правильным mimetype? Ну там еще непонятно, какой программой смотреть будут -- пропаритесь. Может в письме простенько, а потом по ссылке на полную.

Comment: Но нам же всем время от времени приходят на почту сверстанные письма! Почему мое письмо отображается не как сверстанное а как html-разметка?

Comment: Видимо, заголовки нужны:
https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/php-tutorial/php-send-email.php